# How to distinguish between two methods of same name in two modules but when used in one file

Tags: python, django

I have a function with name 'add_member_address' at two places but with different functionalities.
First method is given below which is defined in a view.

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def add_member_address(request, member_id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        pass
    else:
        data = request.POST
        add_member_address(data, member_id) #<-this method is defined in another file.
```

Now when flow reaches inner `add_member_address`, it tries to call this outer method only. So I tried giving the full path of this inner method to distinguish.

```
tenant.services.address_services.add_member_address(data, member_id)
```

where tenant is name of my app which is already registered in settings file. But now this error is thrown.

```
name 'tenant' is not defined
```

Folder structure:

```
project
  ->tenant
    ->services
      -> __init__.py
      -> address_services.py
        -> here is this add_member_address(data, member_id) method
      -> other_services.py
    ->views
      ->members.py
         ->here is this add_member_address(request, member_id) method
```

inside `service/__init__.py` file, all services are imported as below

```
from .address_services import *
from .tag_services import *
```

Please suggest me
1. how can I distinguish between two methods of same name but in two different modules when used in same file.
2. How to use method with full path instead of importing on top of file.

Comment: Briefly: don't use `from module import *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename one, or import only the module and look up the function as an attribute on that.

You can rename an imported name right in the `import` statement:

```
from .address_services import add_member_address as add_address

# use add_address(data, member_id)
```

Using the module name instead:

```
from . import address_services

# use address_services.add_member_address(data, member_id)
```

If you find the latter too verbose, remember you can rename the module reference too:

```
from . import address_services as as_

# use as_.add_member_address(data, member_id)
```

Comment: I don't think `from . import address_services as as` works; `as` is a keyword.

Comment: small typo - instead of `as as` should be something like `as as_` or `as a_s`

Comment: Good point, corrected

Answer (score 0):

Importing everything is anyway not a good practice.

```
from .address_services import add_member_address as add_member_address_address_services
from .tag_services import add_member_address as add_member_address_tag_services
```

Or something similar.